# Ionic 4 - How can I programmatically clear ion-searchbar?

Tags: ionic4

I work with ion-searchbar on Ionic 4.

I would like to know how I can clear the content, if the user clicks on any other button (not the cancel button).

```
<ion-searchbar id="name_of_searchbar" animated placeholder='search' (ionChange)="buscar($event)">
</ion-searchbar>
```

In the function (any another button), I try with: document.getElementById ("name_of_searchbar"). innerHTML = "";

but although it modifies the content, it **also removes** the ion-searchBar

Thank you!

Comment: Add in search bar [(ngModel)]="searchValue" and in ts file declare this variable and in the button tou want to user to clear text with , put inside the button click this.searchValue = "";

Comment: Thanks, perfect!

Comment: @Guille if this worked for you. Close the question. It wasn't clear that a solution had been found I recommend that Mostafa Harb answer the question and you accept it.

Comment: I've added an answer mate.

Comment: how do i close?

Answer (score 1):

Add in search bar [(ngModel)]="searchValue"

```
<ion-searchbar [(ngModel)]="searchValue"  animated placeholder='search' (ionChange)="buscar($event)">
</ion-searchbar>
```

And in ts file:

```
export class PageName {
searchValue:string;
constructor(){}

clearSearch(){
    this.searchValue = "";
}
}
```

In the button you want the user to clear text with , put inside the button click example :

```
<ion-button color="primary" (click)="clearSearch()">empty search</ion-button>
```